# vertically align text after fontawesome characters

Tags: spacing, fontawesome

I'm using `fontawesome` package to include some icons in an article:

```
some_icon some_text
some_icon some_text
some_icon some_text
```

But because these icon characters have variable lengths the texts are not vertically aligned and I get something like:

```
some_icon   some_text
some_icon  some_text
some_icon     some_text
```

What's the most elegant way to align the text parts? I guess I could put each column in an invisible table or minipage or carefully add hspace after each icon but is there a better way?

Comment: wrap each icon in a makebox or parbox of a given width

Comment: Currently your example is quite abstract. Could you be a bit more specific about the intended use?

Comment: `makebox` is exactly what I was looking for!